# OIDC register error : 400 Bad Request: {"error":"invalid_client_metadata","error_description":"Validation failed: Name has already been taken"}

Tags: openid-connect

path(/oidc/register): 400 Bad Request: {"error":"invalid_client_metadata","error_description":"Validation failed: Name has already been taken"} error message when accessing the travel module

It is the  error we see after manually removing the OIDC client in ForestAdmin without deactivating the the client in core.

Answer (score 0):

to fix that

Login to Core instance  as coupasupport user
Access oauth2/clients
Search for the Coupa oidc client id that was originally registered
Delete it
Next time accessing the travel module will register the OIDC client id

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).